# MPMoviePlayerController ipad stuck loading

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

This is the code i am trying to run to show a movie on the ipad.
What happens is i just see loading... on the bottom of the screen.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish) 
         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
NSString *movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mov"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController* mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
          initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];
 mpviewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [self.view addSubview:mpviewController.view];
 MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [mpviewController moviePlayer];
 mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
 [mp prepareToPlay];
 [mp play];
```

Comment: might be file properly not encoded. try playing with itunes

Comment: I converted it to mp4...
Same problem.
And itunes **can** play the mp4 file.

Comment: If you are you running it on the simulator try an actual device.